# Let the viewer stay on the same page and do not flash

Tags: viewers, mac

**Edit 1:**

Following the comment of @kmacinnis, I tried to upgrade my OS X to `Yosemite 10.10.5`, and finally `El Captain 10.11.1`; I also deleted everything under `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/`; however I did not touch other things under `~/Library/` because I am not sure which belong to `Preview`.

The result is that `Preview` still does not work. Even worse than `Yosemite 10.10.1`, each time I re-compile by `make` under a terminal, I have to click on the `Preview` window to refresh (I did not have to do this under `Yosemite 10.10.1`, then it goes systematically to the first page.

PS: the `Preferences` of my `Preview`:
[image]

**Original Post:**

I used to compile tex under `Ubuntu` and view them with `evince` or `okular`. After each re-compilation, the viewers reload automatically the PDF file and stay almost always at the modification location (or last viewed location, which is almost always same as the modification location in practice).

Now, I switch to `Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1`, and I cannot find an ideal reviewer.

With `Preview`, it does reload the PDF automatically after each re-compilation, but it always goes systematically to the first page.

With `Adobe Reader`, it does not reload automatically.

With `TexShop`, the characters are not very clear. And it does not reload automatically for me.

With `Skim`, which is recommended by many people, the problem is that it **flashes** one time, and then goes to the modification location. I guess in the first place, it goes to a position and then adjust a little bit. As a consequence, it is annoying.

Does anyone know a better viewer or a solution?

Answer (score 2):

`Preview` will in fact allow you to do what you want, but you have to set the "On opening documents" option in preferences.

[image]

Comment: Which OS X are you using? I have exactly the same setting, but it always go to the first page.

Comment: Yosemite.  10.10.3, although it's never not worked for me, so I don't think it's a 10.10.2 problem.

Comment: I am downloading `Yosemite 10.10.5` (I don't want to try `El Capitain`, which seems to have a bad feedback)... It does not work on my `Yosemite 10.10.1`, do you remember if it worked when you used `Yosemite 10.10.1`?

Comment: It has always worked, from around Snow Leopard on.  I don't pay that much attention to minor version numbers.  You might also try deleting `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/` (and really, any other files in `~/Library/` that clearly belong to Preview.)

Comment: I just installed `Yosemite 10.10.5`, and it still does not work. Actually, if i open a PDF, close and re-open it, Preview does go to the last viewed page. However, if the pdf is re-generated (by `make` in my case from tex file), it goes to the first page. Did you do your test with re-generation / recompilation? Also, there are lots of files under `~/Library/`, it is not very clear which files belong to Preview.

Comment: It does work for me with regenerated pdfs.  I don't know why it doesn't work for you.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.